# ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, containers, pyodbc

After installing `pyodbc` in a docker container I'm receiving the error:

```
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/connectors/pyodbc.py", line 43, in dbapi
    return __import__("pyodbc")
ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any solution around this?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install#installing-on-linux

Answer (score 6):

You need to install `libodbc.so.2` on your system. The easiest way to do this is through your system's package manager.

For a Red Hat based distro, run: `sudo yum install unixODBC`

For a Debian based distro, run: `sudo apt install unixodbc`

Comment: unixodbc-dev is not really required unless you want to build something like pyodbc from source. `sudo apt install unixodbc` should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: good point, I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution to solve this problem was:

```
sudo apt remove libodbc2
sudo apt install libodbc2
```

I am using a distro based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy)

Answer (score 0):

I foolowed these steps to install the ODBC driver

```
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04 23.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```